# OBJECT_ID() works for all objects BUT views?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, view, objectid

Here I want to retrieve OBJECT_ID of a view as I do with my other objects.
But am facing the fact that it returns NULL instead

```
SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('vw202004-divvy-tripdata.csv')

/*
Result:

NULL

*/
```

Here is shown that the object exists..
Note: I've tried to include DatabaseName and/or SchemaName before ObjectName.

```
SELECT 
  name
  , type
  , object_id
  , [id] = OBJECT_ID(name, type)
FROM sys.views

/*
Result:

name    type    object_id   id
vw202004-divvy-tripdata.csv V   1136136680  NULL

*/
```

Comment: From [`OBJECT_ID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/object-id-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#exceptions): "A user can only view the metadata of securables that the user owns or on which the user has been granted permission. This means that metadata-emitting, built-in functions such as OBJECT_ID may return NULL if the user does not have any permission on the object." [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A663jSMG) says it's not a problem for your own view.

Answer (score 0):

Your view name includes "." and "-", in order to get the actual object name you need to add square brackets (unless your schema is vw202004-divvy-tripdata)

try:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = object_id('[vw202004-divvy-tripdata.csv]')
```

But you don't need to go all the way to sys.views to extract the object_id from the view name just try::

```
SELECT object_id('[vw202004-divvy-tripdata.csv]', 'V')
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe OBJECT_ID returns NULL as its return value is INT and 1136136680 is greater than INT's maximum datalength.

Comment: Object_Id in `sys.objects` is of type INT and the max size of an INT is 2147483647, clearly almost twice as large as 1136136680 .